# Use 64bit browser from Visual Studio (during webapp development)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer-8, windows-server-2008-x64

Is it possible for Visual Studio to launch a 64bit version of IE when debugging an ASP.Net application?

I need to be able to use multiple tabs during debugging and IE 32bit crashes when I open a second tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio Solution Explorer

- click on any Web Form page (.aspx)
- click on "Browse With...", that opens a dialog box
- click the "Add" button
- choose ""C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" for the path (on 64-bit systems, this is IE 64) and for example "Internet Explorer 64-bit" for the friendly name
- click on the "Set as Default" button
- close this dialog box